# Size classes - traitCollectionDidChange crashes with nil value

Tags: swift, size-classes

I have a swift project with a storyboard using Size Classes, a ViewController which conforms to the UITraitEnvironment protocol and have implemented the function `traitCollectionDidChange`.

When I first launch the app `traitCollectionDidChange` is called which seems reasonable - it allows developers to handle the first size class presented by the application, however the `previousTraitCollection` variable passed to it is `nil`. I can't check that this value is `nil` as its NOT optional, and accessing it in any way causes a crash. Changing the parameter to optional in the function declaration causes a build error, complaining that I have not implemented required methods in the protocol.

For now I have managed to work around this by creating a separate function which takes an optional variable of the same type that I can then check against, but I would like to know why this is happening.

If its any use to anyone at all, here is the function I am overriding

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection) {
    // Accessing previousTraitCollection causes a crash
}
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare that the type of the argument is optional, because accessing it forces the compiler to try and unpack the address which causes the crash. Replace it with:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    // Accessing previousTraitCollection causes a crash
}
```

Comment: Already tried this, see the sentence in my post "Changing the parameter to optional in the function declaration causes a build error, complaining that I have not implemented required methods in the protocol."

Comment: Worth reporting as a bug to Apple then - it may be that the function isn't being correctly represented in Swift as an implicitly unwrapped optional, which will fail in this way.